# Add additional text next to "new item" in a library

Tags: library, online

I'd like to add additional text next to "new item" in a sharepoint online library, but I don't want it to be part of the hyperlink to open the form. Here is a code snippet I have in a script editor I found to change "new item" to "new registration", but I also want just text next to it saying something like "to edit click (...) next to item"

```
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
            var ReRenderListView_old = ReRenderListView
                ReRenderListView = function (b, l, e) {
                ReRenderListView_old(b, l, e)
                changeText()


            }
        }, "inplview.js")
        changeText()
    }
);

function changeText(){

    var txt = " Hello"
    var element = document.querySelector('#idHomePageNewItem span:nth-child(2)')
    element ? (element.innerHTML = "New Registration" + txt.small()) : null
}

</script>
```

Is there an easy way to change my var txt to be just text without the hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

Add below:

```
var txt = " Hello"
var element = document.querySelector('#idHomePageNewItem span:nth-child(2)');
element ? (element.innerHTML = "New Registration") : null;
element.closest('a').after(txt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work either. I don't get the " Hello" text after "New Registration".